# gcc and clang both elide the call to the move constructor in the snippet below. Is this correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer, copy-elision

In the code below an object `s` of class `S` is used to initialize an object of class `D` with a direct-initialization `D d(s);`. The conversion function S::operator D() is used to convert the object `s` into a temporary object of type `D`. Then, gcc and clang both elide the explicit call to the move constructor `D(&&)`, to move this temporary object into `d`. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18da94723d63da40).

```
#include <iostream>
struct D;
struct S{ operator D(); };

struct D{
    D(){}
    D(D&&) { std::cout << "move constructor" << '\n'; }
};

S::operator D() { std::cout << "conversion function" << '\n'; return D(); }

int main()
{
    S s;
    D d(s);
}
```

I'm disputing the correctness of this elision, on the following grounds:

1. This case is covered in the first sub-bullet point in §8.5/16 (N3337), which is silent about elision.

   > If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is
   >   copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
   >   type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
   >   destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors
   >   are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload
   >   resolution (13.3). The constructor so selected is called to initialize
   >   the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its
   >   argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is
   >   ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.
2. Note that the next sub-bullet point explicitly mentions the possibility of elision.
3. The call to the move constructor is explicit. How can it be elided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ standard loves to create exceptions to rules defined in one place in a completely different place.

The copy/move elision rules are specified in 12.8/31. There are two copy/move operations to be eliminated in your code.

The first is easy: within `operator D`, the temporary constructed in the return expression is moved to the temporary that represents the function return value. Bullet 3 permits elision of this move.

The second is the move of the temporary function return value to the `d` object. Again, bullet 3 permits the elision.

> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move